# Query does not seem to work with enum

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has various fields including an enum field ('0','1') called 'live'.
The query below works fine but when I ask the query to only return rows where live ='1' it just ignores this and behaves like the first query. If anyone can offer any advice I would be very grateful.

The first query works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname,lname,id FROM members WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR lname LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR firstname LIKE '%$searchquery%' ORDER BY id";
```

But when I add  *AND live = '1'*  it ignores this.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname,lname,id,live FROM members WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR lname LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR firstname LIKE '%$searchquery%' AND live = '1' ORDER BY id";
```

How can I only return rows where live='1'?

Comment: Have you tried using `AND live = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap OR conditions in brackets:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname,lname,id,live FROM members 
WHERE 
(
CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%$searchquery%' 
OR lname LIKE '%$searchquery%' 
OR firstname LIKE '%$searchquery%'
)
AND 
live = '1' ORDER BY id";
```